# AmpScript Block with Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I just started using content builder and noticed it isn't clear how to define an AmpScript block as part of a template. I tried using  but that seems to break the template formatting. Are ampscript blocks supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMPScript is definitely supported in Content Builder.  AMPScript typically *does* jack up the code *in the editor*.

Here's a little trick I use to "pretty up" the AMPScript:

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

/* your big blob of AMPScript goes here */

/* </div> */ 
]%%
```

**Update: Placeholders vs Content Areas**

Content area placeholders for Paste HTML templates `<custom type="content" name="test">` are different than AMPScript blocks.  When you define a template, you can add as many placeholders as you want.  You can then edit the content of those placeholder content areas when you create a new templated email.

AMPScript blocks begin and end with `%%[` and `]%%`.  You can add AMPScript blocks directly in the template HTML or you can add them to the placeholder content area once you create the email based on the template.

Comment: I also have found using the full script tag:  script runat=server language=ampscript **your ampscript here**  /script works too to hide it from displaying - but recently there have been a few times that this now  displays when put inside the body tag and I am not sure what has changed in their UI that makes this happen.

Comment: So in the email studio, you would create a template and then add <custom type="content" name="AMPscript"> just below the <body> section to define the AmpScript block. I tried the same thing in Content Builder but it doesn't create a content block for editing in the template? Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer above to make a distinction between placeholders and AMPScript blocks.

Comment: Hi Adam...I just tried this and found that when I put the div container within the block, it hid everything in the block and left the %% []%%. To get it to work I had to put the div container outside the bracket

Answer (score 1):

Breakdown of each element in the Content Area definition:

1. data-type: must always be "slot"
2. data-key: unique identifier for the content area. Must be unique within each template.
3. data-max-blocks: the maximum number of blocks allowed in that content area. If not defined, it's unlimited.
4. data-allowed-blocks: the types of blocks that can be dragged to that content area. If not defined, all types are allowed in that content area.
5. data-label: the message that appears inside the content area if it's empty. Default is "Drop blocks or content here" if not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder for Content Builder is different than for Classic Content, it's basically div element with custom attributes. Looks like this:

```
<div data-type="slot" data-key="uniqName" data-max-blocks="" data-allowed-blocks="" data-label="Drop content blocks here"></div>
```

I can't find reference in documentation what each attribute is for.